# SQL : Trying to get matching values from 2 Table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

MySQL related

Basically I have two tables:

**Table1 as t1**

```
id | product_id | serial
---|------------|---------
 1 |   100      | "QX0001"
 2 |   108      | "ZK0001"
 3 |   110      | "FS0001"
 4 |   132      | "QX0001"
 5 |   156      | "900002"
 6 |   167      | "900002"
...| ...        | ...
```

> In table1, I can have 1 product having 1 serial.

**Table2 as t2**

```
id | product_id | regex
---|------------|---------
 1 |   100      | "^QX$"
 2 |   100      | "^ZK$"
 3 |   100      | "^PL$"
 4 |   100      | "^90$"
 5 |   108      | "^QX$"
 6 |   108      | "^ZK$"
 7 |   108      | "^PL$"
 8 |   108      | "^90$"
...| ...        | ...
```

> In table 2, I have product_ids having multiple regex code(which match or not to t2.serial).

I was able to get the following result with this query :

```
SELECT 
  t1.product_id,
  t1.serial,
  t2.regex,
  (IF(t1.serial REGEXP t2.regex), "MATCHED", "NOT MATCHED") AS result
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Result :

```
 product_id | regex   | serial | result 
------------|---------|--------|-------
   100      | "^QX$"  | QX0001 | "MATCHED"
   100      | "^ZK$"  | QX0001 | "NOT MATCHED"
   100      | "^PL$"  | QX0001 | "NOT MATCHED"
   100      | "^KP$"  | QX0001 | "NOT MATCHED"
   108      | "^QX$"  | ZK0001 | "NOT MATCHED"
   108      | "^ZK$"  | ZK0001 | "MATCHED"
   108      | "^PL$"  | ZK0001 | "NOT MATCHED"
   108      | "^KP$"  | ZK0001 | "NOT MATCHED"
   156      | "^QX$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   156      | "^ZK$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   156      | "^PL$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   156      | "^KP$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   167      | "^QX$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   167      | "^ZK$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   167      | "^PL$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   167      | "^KP$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
...         | ...     | ....   | ...
```

My task is that I have to filter my results based on group. If the group of the product_ids (100,108,110,132,156,etc..) does not have any "MATCHED" value on `result` field like we see for product_id 156 and 167, ONLY those results musts be displayed.

How can I achieve this ?

**Final/Expected result :**

```
product_id | regex   | serial | result 
------------|---------|--------|-------
   156      | "^QX$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   156      | "^ZK$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   156      | "^PL$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   156      | "^KP$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   167      | "^QX$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   167      | "^ZK$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   167      | "^PL$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
   167      | "^KP$"  | 900002 | "NOT MATCHED"
...         | ...     | ...    | ...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can filter this out but I would recommend using a common table expression for readability.

```
WITH CTE as (
SELECT 
  t1.product_id,
  t1.serial,
  t2.regex,
  (IF(t1.serial REGEXP t2.regex), "MATCHED", "NOT MATCHED") AS result
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE product_id NOT IN (
  SELECT product_id FROM CTE WHERE result = 'MATCHED'
)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Will this filter per group ?  Because my concern is that it should return group per product_ids which have only "NOT MATCHED" after INNER JOIN with table2.  Like you see 156 and 167.

Comment: Also, the query should be like : it should first group by product_ids
100
100
100
108
108
156
156
156
167
167


Then check each serial of that particular product_id group and finally see if It's MATCHED or not.

Can we achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried my solution? What were the results?